# How to replace value in pandas with value in the same row but in a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have [this dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW9da.png). I want to replace all the 'DEBIT' values in the 'Payee' column to their corresponding value in the 'Memo' column.

e.g. the first DEBIT value should be replaced with 'FC02-0224-0185673-83 mom  ball tickets' and so on and so forth.

I have experimented with some replace and [mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3AI1.png) functions to no avail.

Any ideas on how to do this with syntax examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: images of data/code are not acceptable, please provide reproducible **text**

Comment: try this `df.Payee[df.Payee == 'DEBIT'] = df.Memo`

Comment: Please post your question in pure text form:  
 [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @mozway My code is not reproducible as the dataframe is based on an uploaded CSV file, and so it will change everytime. I just need a way of replacing every DEBIT value that exists with the value in the Memo column in the same row.

Comment: @BerlinBenilo Sorry, I don't think I can do that as I do not have enough reputation. If you post it as an answer I will gladly mark it correct. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df.Payee[df.Payee == 'DEBIT'] = df.Memo
```